# How can I disable all dates up to 14 days ahead of the current date in Vue Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, vue.js, datepicker

I have seen similar questions asked but none answer my question. I have a vue js datepicker, and i need to allow the user to pick a date, but this date can not be before 2 weeks ahead of the current date. So i need all dates disabled, and then enabled starting 14 days from now.

At the moment i have it as below, so can disable the dates up until the current date, can anyone adise on disabling the next 14 days also?

```js
import Datepicker from 'vuejs-datepicker'
export default {
    components: {
        Datepicker
    },
    data() {
        return {
            model: {
                date: ''
            },
            DatePickerFormat: 'dd/MM/yyyy',
            disabledDates: {
                to: new Date(Date.now() - 864000) 
            },

        };
    },

};
```

```html
<datepicker
  class="form-control" 
  id="customer_start_date"
  v-model="date"
  :format="DatePickerFormat"
  :disabledDates="disabledDates">
</datepicker>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
data() {

    return {
    
        //..
        ranges: [{ // Disable dates in given ranges (exclusive).
            from: new Date(),
            to: new Date(new Date().getTime() + (14 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the proper amount of time. In yours, you are subtracting. Also, you were not setting your v-model correctly and it was causing an error in vue. This is also fixed in the example, which now blocks all dates previous to 2wks in the future from the current time.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: `
    <vuejs-datepicker
      class="form-control" 
      id="customer_start_date"
      v-model="date"
      :format="DatePickerFormat"
      :disabledDates="disabledDates">
    </vuejs-datepicker>
  `,
  components: {
        vuejsDatepicker
    },
    data() {
        return {
            date: '',
            DatePickerFormat: 'dd/MM/yyyy',
            disabledDates: {
                to: new Date(Date.now() + (14 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) 
            },

        };
    },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuejs-datepicker"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```